# Android: dynamoDB query with mapper returns null - time out

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb

since two weeks i am trying and I would be very happy if someone could help me. I execute the query from within an AsyncTask. writing to aws via mapper.save works for that class and table. I can even perfom a table scan from where i try to mapper.load. and it works. But mapper.load wont work. My log out points to a timeout, but aws support says thats not it.

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new  AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
        ddbClient.setEndpoint("dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);
        TraceForDB trace = mapper.load(TraceForDB.class, 123);
```

it returns null and my logcat says:

```
    10-31 07:53:20.234    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ Loading credentials from SharedPreferences
10-31 07:53:20.235    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/DDBQuery﹕ Loading Message
10-31 07:53:20.251    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest I/System.out﹕ [CDS]rx timeout:15000
10-31 07:53:20.251    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x540395e8 sslWrite buf=0x4109d568 len=1679 write_timeout_millis=0
10-31 07:53:20.251    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ Doing SSL_write() with 1679 bytes to go ssl=0x540395e8, appData=0x5403c7c8
10-31 07:53:20.252    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ Returned from SSL_write() with result 1679, error code 0 ssl=0x540395e8, appData=0x5403c7c8
10-31 07:53:20.253    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x540395e8 sslRead buf=0x410813f0 len=1,timeo=15000
10-31 07:53:20.253    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x540395e8, appData=0x5403c7c8
10-31 07:53:20.253    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ Returned from SSL_Read() with result -1, error code 2 ssl=0x540395e8, appData=0x5403c7c8
10-31 07:53:20.253    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ sslSelect type=READ fd=57 appData=0x5403c7c8 timeout_millis=15000
10-31 07:53:20.295    4724-4730/com.example.jan.tracestest D/jdwp﹕ received file descriptor 46 from ADB
10-31 07:53:20.299    4724-4730/com.example.jan.tracestest D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-31 07:53:20.301    4724-4730/com.example.jan.tracestest D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-31 07:53:20.301    4724-4730/com.example.jan.tracestest D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000058, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
10-31 07:53:20.302    4724-4730/com.example.jan.tracestest D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-31 07:53:20.302    4724-4730/com.example.jan.tracestest D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x17, id=0x40000059, flags=0x0, dataLen=0xC
10-31 07:53:20.303    4724-4730/com.example.jan.tracestest D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-31 07:53:20.303    4724-4730/com.example.jan.tracestest D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x4000005A, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
10-31 07:53:20.304    4724-4730/com.example.jan.tracestest D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-31 07:53:20.304    4724-4730/com.example.jan.tracestest D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x4000005B, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
10-31 07:53:20.305    4724-4730/com.example.jan.tracestest D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-31 07:53:20.305    4724-4730/com.example.jan.tracestest D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000005C, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
10-31 07:53:20.332    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ sslSelect READ fd=57 appData=0x5403c7c8 timeout_millis=15000 => 1
10-31 07:53:20.332    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x540395e8, appData=0x5403c7c8
10-31 07:53:20.332    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x540395e8, appData=0x5403c7c8
10-31 07:53:20.332    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x540395e8 sslRead buf=0x4150b3b8 len=1,timeo=15000
10-31 07:53:20.332    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x540395e8, appData=0x5403c7c8
10-31 07:53:20.332    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x540395e8, appData=0x5403c7c8
10-31 07:53:20.332    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x540395e8 sslRead buf=0x4150b400 len=1,timeo=15000
10-31 07:53:20.332    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x540395e8, appData=0x5403c7c8
10-31 07:53:20.332    4724-4799/com.example.jan.tracestest D/NativeCrypto﹕ Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x540395e8, appData=0x5403c7c8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it was a problem wit the declaration within the mapper class. The id had to be a Long not a long....  jap that easy...